# opencv aruco estimatePoseSingleMarkers python

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I am trying to find aruco markers using w10, python 3.6, opencv2.

I can detect markers but fail on this step

```
rvec, tvec = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs) # For a single marker
```

I get this python exception:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

leaving out tvec in the result list does not throw the error but then I do not have the translation info.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, it seems like there are 3 arrays that need to be unpacked, so try this

```
rvec, tvec, _ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
```

Not sure what the third array is about.

Comment: The third return value is _objPoints: "array of object points of all the marker corners".  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga84dd2e88f3e8c3255eb78e0f79571bd1

Answer (score 0):

use only one variable to get what is returned by aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers .
then take only the first two values like in the below code.

```
ret = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners,marker_size,cameraMatrix=cameraMatrix,distCoeffs=cameraDistortion)
(rvec, tvec) = (ret[0][0, 0, :], ret[1][0, 0, :])
```